# Theming the action bar

Tags: android, android-studio

I have created a super simple theme:

```
<style name="MyTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/MyActionBar</item>
</style>

<style name="MyActionBar" parent="@android:style/Widget.Holo.Light.ActionBar">
    <item name="android:background">@color/UglyRed</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/RepulsiveGreen</item>
</style>
```

In the manifest I set this theme for my activity.
The problem is that the action bar appears in plain grey with white text. It seems my theme settings are completely ignored.

When I add other settings to the theme (e.g. the activity's main text color) it works. Only the action bar won't get colored correctly...

Answer (score 1):

For AppCompat themes you skip the `android` prefix:

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <item name="actionBarStyle">@style/MyActionBar</item>
    <item name="actionMenuTextColor">#0000FF</item>
</style>

<style name="MyActionBar" parent="Widget.AppCompat.Light.ActionBar">
    <item name="background">@drawable/annoying_red</item>
    <item name="titleTextStyle">@style/TitleStyle</item>
</style>
<style name="TitleStyle" parent="TextAppearance.AppCompat">
    <item name="android:textColor">#00FF00</item>
</style>
```

annoying_red.xml:

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <solid android:color="#FF0000"/>
</shape>
```

Comment: I just tried your code. But there is still no effect :-(

Comment: @Boris does your class extend `ActionBarActivity`?

Comment: @Boris it's good. But I'm not sure why this doesn't work then :/

Answer (score 0):

Double check that you aren't setting the action bar theme programmatically (e.g. in your activity.java).

Also, double check your activity.xml for anything that may possibly be overriding your manifest's changes to the actionbar.

Comment: Done. I can't see anything that could interfere with the action bar theming.